# How to write an array in the last of the list in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to write my data to the list, but not to overrite. I want to be able to write the same data but to diferent places on the same array in firebase.

like:

history
----- 0 ----user: test1
------1 ----user:test2
------2 ---- user: test1

but on my code, i can only wrote to the 0, and not create new data. Its like the data is getting overrited.

Javasript:

```
this.test = [{[user]: { data.... }];

public af: AngularFireDatabase

 this.af.object("/history").set(this.teste);
```

Comment: Please be more precise on what exact result you expect. It is not very clear IMHO.

Comment: see if u understand it now

Comment: Is `this.test` containing the entire array or just the element you want to add?

Comment: Just the element i want to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is in your first few words:

> I want to write my data to the list

Since you mention a **list**, you should use the [AngularFire `list()` API](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#saving-data) - not its `object()` API as you're doing now. According to the documentation, adding an item to a list would work something like this:

```
this.af.list("/history").push(this.teste);
```

Note that you will get Firebase push IDs instead of the `0`, `1`, `2` in your question, as Firebase doesn't use sequential incremental indexes as explained here [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Thanks! I will do that!! I really forgot about the list in firebase. That should work